# linux kernel head file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

i am trying to know the size of task_struct. thus i have downloaded the linux source code from the website and i have generated the head files via typing the command `make headers_install` into terminal in the source code file root directory.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(struct task_struct)).
    return 0;
}
```

typing the command to the termial to compile and source code `gcc -g -I *path/to/linux*-source/usr/include test.c -o test`. However the terminal shows struct task_struct does not define stuff.
Could any guys to help me to figure it out? Really appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK the struct will be used in kernel only and is not exposed to the user land

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This struct is for kernel internal use only. It's definition is pretty long and largely varies  depending on kernel configuration. So, the struct size also varies depending on kernel configuration, and you can't get it from user-space.

Unless, you extract kernel config, which is bad idea, as for me. The better one is to write a kernel module.

Comment: thanks for you help. More, could you please give more help to let me know what i need to do? which means the steps to write the kernel module. sharing the link or something else as a reference is also welcomed. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: This is a pretty simple guide for kernel module programming http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/ You can change first example to do what you want with a little affort.